# How do I Build and Publish .Net Website using Azure DevOPs Pipeline

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, vs-web-site-project

Is there support for building and publishing a .net Website (not a webapp) in Azure Devops?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: Did you get a solution to deployment of an asp.net website? It does not produce a package and IISWebAppDeploymentOnMachineGroup is built around a package, right?

Comment: I am also searching for this. Is there any update on this? Could you please tell me if you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I Build and Publish .Net Website using Azure DevOPs Pipeline

The short answer is yes.

Azure DevOPs support configure continuous integration (CI) and continuous delivery (CD) for .NET core or ASP.NET application, the ASP.NET application including the ASP.NET web site.

There is a template ASP.NET, which you can use it to build the website project (Adjust your tasks as needed):

[image]

Check this document Continuous [Integration Using Azure DevOps Pipelines And .NET Project](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/continuous-integration-using-azure-devops-and-net-project/) for some more details.

Comment: Was the question about a Website, not a Web Application. This template is for a web application.

Comment: That Azure Task is for the wrong kind of solution; It does not reflect the needs the original poster and is not helpful to people looking for a solution.  Try instead to read the original post and understand the needs of the person asking the question before spamming an automated and incorrect response.  I'm having the same issue as the OP and your solution does not work.